# I've hit some shortcut and now my pivot point isn't centered on the object

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-editor

Normally when you select an object, any gizmos like the move axis are at the object's center. However, I've done something and that point is moving around to the object's edges and vertices when the mouse hovers over it. Its making it frustrating to work. How can I switch this back?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I clicked shift v at one point. Clicking v again fixed it